# Show that a Set is dense in $(C[0,1],|| \cdot| |_\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lipschitz-functions

I have to show that the set: $$M :=\{f\in C[0,1]:\exists L \gt 0 \: \forall x,y \in [0,1] \space \space \space |f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y| \} $$
is dense in $(C[0,1],|| \cdot|  |_\infty)$

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint : polynomials on bounded sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Lipschitz.